# Does RestSharp have cache

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, restsharp

I have a simple question, that I can't find a straight answer:

Does RestSharp cache request made? If it does, how much time does the cache last and how can i change it? If it doesn't, how can I add cache to RestSharp?

I'm using it in an Asp.net MVC app deployed to Azure web application.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What makes you think it does?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker apparently it does under the hood, based on codeCaster's answer

Comment: I'm trying to ask you show an example of a request that is cached that you didn't expect to be but was. Right now it all depends on how your app is set up.

Comment: unfortunately due to my lack of knowledge on this i don't know how to see if a request was using cache or not. I was asking this because i want to increase the duration of the cache. From what i've searched i haven't found anywhere the duration of the cache nor how to change it.

Answer (score 4):

RestSharp doesn't cache by itself, but under the hood the framework classes it uses do, through WinInet.

You can bypass this cache with conditional requests, or by adding a cache buster to the query string.

This all is influenced by the Cache Policy, see [MSDN: Cache Policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0eywff03(v=vs.110).aspx).

See also [How to clear the cache of HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532211/how-to-clear-the-cache-of-httpwebrequest), [WP7 - Prevent RestSharp from caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232514/wp7-prevent-restsharp-from-caching), [Refreshing in RestSharp for Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056409/refreshing-in-restsharp-for-windows-phone) and so on.

Comment: in fact i want to provably increase the cache duration.

Comment: Then see the WinInet documentation and the [Cache Policy documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0eywff03(v=vs.110).aspx) that abstracts this functionality.

Comment: i've been looking into HttpRequestCachePolicy, but restsharp doesn't allow you to set cache policies. i have the nuget version 105.1.0

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/401

```cs
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
client.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.Revalidate);
```